# DyanmoDB shows Item Count = 0, not being populated, and not working in Appsync query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I have added an index to my DynamoDB table in order to order the results but it doesn't appear to be doing anything. In the DyanmoDB dashboard it shows with 0 size and 0 item count.

[image]

There are several hundred items in the table and they all have an id (the primary key) and a created value. I didn't set a range property when I created the table. The items in the picture below are in the correct order but the response via appsync is not.

[image]

I have added the index to the query which returns all the items and it does not seem to do anything, the order of the items is the same with or without the index:

```
"version" : "2017-02-28",
"operation" : "Scan",
"index" : "id-created-index",
"limit": $util.defaultIfNull(${ctx.args.limit}, 20),
"nextToken": $util.toJson($util.defaultIfNullOrBlank($ctx.args.nextToken, null))
```

What am I missing? Has the index not been built or is there something else I need to do to use it in a query?

Update:
The index now shows the correct item_count although it is still not ordering the results:

[image]

Comment: The size and the count values in the console are not real time. They are updated roughly every 6 hours per the console. So that is red herring as part of your investigation into the issue with the sorting. I originally added this as an answer, but realized it is not the answer to your actual issue.

Comment: You're right, the index is indeed now showing an item_count of 501. However this has not changed the fact the index is not ordering the results

Comment: Agreed. That is why I removed it as an answer and changed it to a comment. I just wanted to make sure that you were not factoring that aspect as part of your investigation. Let me think more about the ordering and try a few things.

Answer (score 1):

Your base table has a partition key of `id` and no sort key. By definition this means each item in your table has a unique `id`.

Your GSI has a partition key of `id` and a sort key of `created`. Data is sorted by the created attribute *within each partition key*. As each of your ids is unique, the sort key is basically not doing anything.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the partition key should not be unique then? Is the only way to get an ordered set of results to have a partition key that is the same for all rows?

Comment: In DynamoDB the only way to get ordered results is using a sort key, and that's only effective within a partition. Using a single partition key for the whole table would be a bad idea. The right solution here is to do your sorting client side.

Answer (score 0):

Scan operations against a table or index returns the results in a random order. In order to have results sorted coming from DynamoDB, you'll need to run a Query operation, where the partition/hash key is fixed, and results will be sorted according to the sort key. However, since your table/GSI always have unique IDs, there's no additional records within a single partition (the id).

So yes, if you wanted results ordered by `created`, you'd need to have a fixed attribute on your table set as the partition key for your Index. The caveat here is that all your records in the index would belong to a single partition, which would be a bottleneck. There are a few ways around this; one way would be to see if there's a different access pattern where you can keep a different attribute fixed to query against (ie. `owner_id`). If the number of records are low enough, filtering on the client side is probably the best option.